# Newly Transplanted Palm with Fungus Issue

Tags: fungus, palm

[image]

Hello all.  I had 2 palms put in June 9th  2020.  Both of them were hurricane cut.  The healthy one, not pictured here, still had a couple of fronds and looks great. The other - these photos - has zero fronds and also is having fungal issues.

The first picture is the original fungus I saw -  just dark bark and some white spotty fungus; the installer had me go up to the nursery and get ferti-lome 2-n-1 systemic; no instructions given so we followed the packaging based on foot height of palm.  I applied the ferti-lome yesterday 6.22.2020.   This AM there is a different fungus on the OTHER side of the tree - picture 2- a yellow powdery looking fungus that is clearly rapid growing.  This palm also has  some holes with black dead bark.

I will contact the installer again but wanted some insight as I am not sure what to even ask.  Can applying the ferti-lome make fungus come OUT?  I am clueless here and hoping the photos show up.

[image]

[image]

Adding a picture updated from 4 hours later noon on 6.22.2020
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone,  the landscaper thinks it is getting too much water.  I also contacted Univsity of FL; sounds like just need to supplement at this point approx 5 gallons a week or twice weekly in summer / drought.  So I will see how this goes.  The landscaper said I can use a topical fungicide also.   Any other input welcomed!

Comment: I have no experience with such large trees.  But I think it's possible that it has internal injuries and the fungus may be widespread already.  It has no fronds, but it does it have any green tips at the top ?